# Сортировка пузырьком двумерного массива

Tags: java

Есть задача. Написать  метод, получающий на вход квадратную матрицу и возвращающий новую матрицу, где чётные строки отсортированы  по возрастанию, а нечётные по убыванию.
У меня был рабочий метод сортировку пузырьками. Когда я его перенес на двумерный массив получил проблему с кодом. Массив не сортируется. Я даже упросил код, чтобы просто все сортировалось по возрастанию.

```java
package Homework2;
import static evening2.ManyDimAr1.*;

public class Wer {
    public static int[][] sort(int[][] ar) {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            boolean sorted = false;
            while (!sorted) {
                sorted = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < ar.length - 1; j++) {
                    if (ar[i][j] > ar[i][j + 1]) {
                        System.out.println(ar[i][j]);
                        temp = ar[i][j];
                        ar[i][j] = ar[i][j + 1];
                        ar[i][j + 1] = temp;
                        sorted = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] ar = new int[][]{{3157}, {2498}, {3557}, {8613}};
        sort(ar);
    }
}
```

Comment: как ни странно, сортировка пузырьком обычно делается с помощью двойного цикла. + вам еще один цикл нужен на строки первого уровня. Итого, должно быть три цикла. а у вас два. зы: вынесите сортировку строки в отдельную функцию.

Comment: Так у меня и так двойной цикл. Одинарный цикл для одномерной матрицы, двойной для двумерной. Я перебираю в коде строки в первом цикле, во втором, вложенном, сортирую столбцы. Что не так?

Comment: А... как Вы узнали, что массив не сортируется?

Comment: @teran Там есть внешний цикл пузырька - while

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена. Я просто идиот ))). Забыл числа через запятую поставить. )))

Comment: @MBo действительно ) пропустил что-то